# Issue Upload Image in Folder using PHP

Tags: php, database, file-upload

I'm struggling how to upload a picture in folder called uploads and insert name of image in database. Do you know how to make this work? Thanks

**index.php**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Select image to upload:
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Upload.php**

```
// Connect the localhost for project 1
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'pju2173';
$user = 'pju2173';
$pwd = 'fr1end';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pwd);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    return 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target_dir = "Uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file.time().$image);

    $query = "INSERT INTO ImageTable(image) VALUES(:image)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":image", $image);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if($result){
        echo "Uploaded";
    }
    else{
        echo "Something wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: your form action seems incorrect if you are using upload.php as your action file

Comment: Besides that ^ - Sidenote: On a * NIX system, `Uploads` and `uploads` are two different animals. Check for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible helps

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Complete Upload File PHP Script

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm really appreciated that you were willing to help me. Thank you very much!